# lazy load images fullpage js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js for a website and want to know have the images in each slide only load when the person is on that slide to reduce the page load time. Fullpage comes with this call back that will fire on the slide load

```
afterSlideLoad: function(slideIndex, index){}
```

So basically my plan was to use a place holder image and switch out the src and href with a data attribute when the page loads. The script seems to be work fine but when I load the page and use chrome inspector the image is still being loaded to the page when not on that slide even though the script hasnt fired.

```
<a href="" data-lightbox="golf-1" data-title="Test"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="" data-echo="img/res/golf/1-1.jpg" class="animateHidden"></a>

afterSlideLoad: function(slideIndex, index){
    $(this).find( "img" ).each(function() {
         var orginalImg = $(this).attr('data-echo');
         $(this).attr("src", orginalImg);
         $(this).parent().attr('href', orginalImg);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fullPage.js provides a lazy load option in its latest version (2.6.6 at the moment).

[Check it out](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#lazy-loading)

Answer (score 0):

This code does work. I noticed in the dev tools the image was getting called from an old js file I had preloading images. Once I got rid of that this worked just fine.